# Print Preview for PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, printing, print-preview

I want to create an application where in I can display "print preview" on a PDF file.
For example, if I set the N-up option to 4, 4 pages of the pdf will be displayed in page 1, etc.

I wanted to create something similar with the print preview of PrinterShare app.

An idea that I have in mind:
1) Read pdf (like an image), then draw the changes manually, e.g. if N-up, draw the image 4 times in a page while considering the new height/width (in this case, height and width will be set to 1/4 of original).

Do you have other ideas?
Or do you know of any libraries for "print previews"?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean having a Print Preview before Air Print ?

Comment: Not necessarily AirPrint since we are also considering other methods/protocols in printing.

Comment: Can you show us your existing codes ?

Comment: I do not have existing codes yet. I am still gathering ideas on how to proceed with this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for solid programming questions. Please search & try to implement some codes & get back here.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of any benefit in implementing some codes for my question. But, first of all, what part of the code do you want to see? I may be able to come up with something depending on your answer.

Comment: the code of rendering PDF on screen.

Comment: Rendering PDF on screen, without considering printing options?

Comment: I think the reason for marking this question as off-topic is wrong.
Firstly, this is not a question about code I've written, since I have not written any code yet. This question is about the possible approaches to a problem (in this case, the "print preview" problem).
Maybe it can be considered as a "software algorithm" question? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
  
If you have an idea on how to edit this question, feel free to edit or post a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea seems possible. For each option you want to consider, you can translate it to PDF drawing code.

For example, N-up can be done by scaling the previous PDF, and then redrawing it N times on the same page.
Margin can be done by changing your starting positions when drawing the PDF.

You can follow this guide for drawing to a PDF:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

You can also refer to the following stackoverflow question:
[Convert a PDF to one page PDF reason for this is PDF pages doesnot have same page height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025701/convert-a-pdf-to-one-page-pdf)
It has sample codes for drawing PDF.